# Fill out sudoku board - backtracking solution question

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I wrote the following solution for the Leetcode question copied below:

> Write a program to solve a Sudoku puzzle by filling the empty cells.
>
> A sudoku solution must satisfy all of the following rules:
>
> Each of the digits 1-9 must occur exactly once in each row. Each of
>   the digits 1-9 must occur exactly once in each column. Each of the the
>   digits 1-9 must occur exactly once in each of the 9 3x3 sub-boxes of
>   the grid. Empty cells are indicated by the character '.'.
>   Note:
>
> The given board contain only digits 1-9 and the character '.'. You may
>   assume that the given Sudoku puzzle will have a single unique
>   solution. The given board size is always 9x9.

```
class Solution:
    def solveSudoku(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
        """
        EMPTY_CELL = '.'
        target = set(str(n) for n in range(1, 10))

        def _validate():
          cols = [[board[r][c] for r in range(9)] for c in range(9)]
          boxes = []
          for i in (0, 3, 6):
            for j in (0, 3, 6):
              boxes.append([board[a][b] for a in range(i, i + 3) for b in range(j, j + 3)])

          valid_rows = all(set(row) == target for row in board)
          valid_cols = valid_rows and all(set(col) == target for col in cols)
          valid_boxes = valid_cols and all(set(box) == target for box in boxes)
          return valid_boxes


        def helper(r, c):
          if c == len(board[0]):
            return helper(r + 1, 0)

          if r == len(board):
            return _validate()

          if not board[r][c] == EMPTY_CELL:
            return helper(r, c + 1)

          for n in range(1, 10):
            board[r][c] = str(n) 
            if helper(r, c + 1):
              return True 

          return False

        helper(0, 0)
```

Here's my strategy in plain English. For every cell that is empty, I try placing a number in that cell, and recursing on the remainder of the board. If that doesn't lead to a valid solution, I backtrack, increment the number, and recurse having placed that number in the empty cell instead.

My validate function is returning `False` for everything, and I'm ending up with a board with `9`'s in the empty spaces. The problem guarantees that there IS a correct solution for every test case. I've walked through this code dozens of times and am unable to see what the issue is.

(I understand that I could use constraint propagation to speed up the solution, but the current problem isn't that my solution is too slow - it is that its *incorrect*).

Anyone see why? Also, in case this is unclear from the problem statement, each digit is supposed to be a string.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Your validate function *will* return true if you feed it a correct solution. You can verify this yourself by feeding it a solved sudoku board:

```
solved_text = '''435269781
682571493
197834562
826195347
374682915
951743628
519326874
248957136
763418259'''

solved_board = [ list(line) for line in solved_text.split('\n') ]
```

There are two problems. First, you do not actually search the complete space of solutions. If you print each complete board passed into `_validate()`, you will notice something odd: the whole board is always in lexical order! This is not the 10^81 set of possible boards. This can be fixed by simply omitting these two lines of code:

```
if not board[r][c] == EMPTY_CELL:
    return helper(r, c + 1)
```

These are causing a problem because you mutate board state as a side affect as you go but do not clean-up (put back empty cells) while backtracking. You can simply omit those two lines (so that the algorithm in `helper()` never cares about what is to the right in the (r,c) lexical ordering) or by adding code to set `board[r][c] = EMPTY_CELL` when back-tracking.

The other problem is that because you only run validation on complete boards, and because your validation function can only check complete boards for correctness, your algorithm really will have to plow through all 10^81 possible boards before it finds a solution. This isn't just slow, it's completely intractable! Instead, you should rewrite your validation function so that it can validate a *partial* board. For example, if the first row is ['1', '1', '.', ..., '.'], it should return False, but if the first row is ['1', '2', '.', ..., '.'] it should return True because there are no problems so far. Obviously, you will also have to call _validate() at every step now, not just when the board is complete... but this is worth it because otherwise you will spend enormous amounts of time exploring boards which are obviously never going to work.

You will need to fix *both* problems before your algorithm will work.

Comment: I understand that it'll be too slow, but I'm not sure I understand why omitting those two lines of code fixes the issue. I'm not restoring state in the typical way because that isn't necessary here. I want to recurse down putting a number on a cell, and then backtrack if that doesn't work, and change it to another number. Passing the recursive function along if its not an empty cell should be fine, because eventually the backtracking will lead to modifying the original cell. Can you explain this further?

Comment: Why would I want to put back empty cells? I should fill in every empty cell as I go, and then backtrack, and flip the number that I first put in the empty cell to the next number, and recurse down that path instead. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the problem. 

Take (0,0). I recurse down having placed a number there, and I mutate each location on my way down. if I hit a dead end, as I pop off each stack frame, I have to undo the changes I made in that cell.

Comment: However, I do not think it's correct to omit checking if the board[r][c] is an empty cell. If I don't make that check, I'll end up overriding given values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not having a right validation! Your validation only works for the final solution. Unless you are trying to general all possible fill-outs for your sudoku, this validation do not give you any check (and always false).

The pseudo-code of what a backtracking algorithm in my mind is the following:

1. Scan from cell (0,0) up to cell (8,8), find an empty one
2. Test out options "1" to "9"

   1. call validation on each option, if valid, recur to the scan line above
   2. if failed validation, try other option
   3. if exhaused all options "1" to "9", previous level of recursion is invalid, try another one

So the validation is not to check if all rows, columns, boxes have 1 to 9, but to check if they have no duplicate! In python code, it means `len(x) == len(set(x))` for `x` the row, column, or box, which takes only "1" to "9" but not ".".